# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :' when trying to get data from instagram/user_name/media

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to get jsonp from https://www.instagram.com/user_name/media/

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media?callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
   });
```

As a result I have "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
When I' m trying to get json I have the next error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This mistake repeats both on local host, as well as on github.io.
I should mention, that using back-end is not allowed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure ACAO header is present. you are using `www.instagram.com ` and not `api.instagram.com`

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```
jQuery.ajax = function (d) {
    var b = location.protocol,
    e = RegExp(b + "//" + location.hostname),
    f = "http" + (/^https/.test(b) ? "s" : "") + "://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?";
    return function (a) {
        var c = a.url;
        if (/get/i.test(a.type) && !/json/i.test(a.dataType) && !e.test(c) && /:\/\//.test(c)) {
            a.url = f;
            a.dataType = "json";
            a.data = {
                q: 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"'.replace("{URL}", c + (a.data ? (/\?/.test(c) ? "&" : "?") + jQuery.param(a.data) : "")),
                format: "xml"
            };
            !a.success && a.complete && (a.success = a.complete, delete a.complete);
            var b = a.success;
            a.success = function (a) {
                b && b.call(this, {
                    responseText: (a.results[0] || "").replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, "")
                }, "success")
            }
        }
        return d.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}(jQuery.ajax);
```